# undefined is not a function (near '...reactDevTools.connectToDevTools...')

Tags: xcode, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have spent over a day trying to get map view to work and along the way I picked up this error that I can't find anywhere at all on the internet. The error code shows up on iOS simulator with a red screen as is typical for react native.

I tried reinstalling the Dev Tools and that didn't work.

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name":"P77",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-native": "0.57.8",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.22.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.1.0",
    "react-navigation": "git+https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation.git"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.1",
    "react-devtools": "^3.4.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

please help

Comment: I am facing same issue when for android app

Comment: When reading the docs: With npm, you can run npm install --save-dev react-devtools, add "react-devtools": "react-devtools" to the scripts section in your package.json, and then run npm run react-devtools from your project folder to open the DevTools.

And I dont see that you updated the "scripts" in your package.json ?

Comment: Thank you for the answer; I did try that solution just now, and nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

I found out an answer that works for me, but I'm not sure. Maybe this can help people in the future. I ran:

```
"yarn add eslint-config-rallycoding --dev" 
"npm start"
```

(in project directory)